# Logging Fields of Embed messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, discord.js

I am trying to log the contents of an embed received from a certain bot. I tried the basic stuffs.Pls have a look and tell me what did i do wrong and how to improve. Thanks in advance

```
for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++){  

       message.embeds[i] 
       message.embeds[i].fields
       console.log(message.embeds[i].fields.values.toString())    
}
```

Comment: What does the output of `console.log(message.embeds[i].fields.values.toString())` tell you? What is the specific problem? Saying *its not working* doesn't tell us much.

Answer (score 0):

Well i tried a different approach

```
message.embeds.forEach(async embed => {
            embed.fields.forEach(async field => {
                //stuffs
                }
            })
        })
```

this seemed to work